# "Request Entity Too Large" en Laravel y SoapWrapper

Tags: laravel, webservice, soap, lumen

Tengo un api en laravel que usa la l libreria Soap para enviar datos y recibir al momento de traer un ejemplo 1000 datos el web service lo hace bien , pero al momento de yo enviarle un json con los mimso datos saca el siguiente error.

**SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Request Entity Too Large in /var/www/vendor/artisaninweb/laravel-soap/src/Artisaninweb/SoapWrapper/Client.php:189 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__soapCall('GuardarPedidos', Array, Array, NULL, Array)**

A simple vista yo diria es que el problema es del web service que tiene un limite, pero no se si es problema mio o del web service, y en caso tal que puedo hacer

Comment: Efectivamente es  problema del  web service , si no tienes control sobre el , tendrás que ponerte en contacto con el administrador , aquí tienes mas detalle  [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942894/uncaught-soapfault-exception-http-request-entity-too-large)

Comment: LIsto gracias, lo que pasa es que tambien tengo responsabilidad en el web service, y no se que modificarle